# Why is my MEF TypeCatalog empty?

Tags: .net, mef, composition

When I run the code below using an `AssemblyCatalog` and a folder of assemblies each containing an `IBusinessModule`, I can iterate the catalog and perform operations with each part.

When I try as follows, substituting `IApplicationArea` for `IBusinessModule` and `TypeCatalog` for `AssemblyCatalog`, I end up with no parts.

My project contains ten classes that implement IApplicationArea and are decorated with `[Export(typeof(IApplicationArea))]`.

What is the difference here and why do I get no parts?

Comment: In the TypeCatalog, are you using the type of the interface or the types implementing the interface? It will not work if you use the interface.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem but with importing parts in Azure worker role is not working while it works when importing the same parts in console application.

But my problem was related to open generic exports only, the other exports are working just fine.

When switched the composition to [Microsoft.Composition](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Composition/) it works. Note that Microsoft.Composition is lightweight version of the .Net framework 4.5 Microsoft.ComponentModel.Composition Mef

I asked this question in several forums but no answer yet.

My Question in stackoverflow is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339051/azure-mef-open-generics)